# What to do with questions that require a list of answers?

Tags: discussion

There are questions which can only be answered by a list of alternatives, e.g. a list of possible translations. For example of such question, see [What do people in Russia say about doing some hard tedious work?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/q/2785)

Naturally, one user proposes his list of translations, than another user comes and proposes another list, which may partially intersect with the list of the first user, etc. In such situations, I always get htese questions:

1. Who gave the correct answer?
2. If the list contains both a very good and a very bad translation, should I upvote or downvote?
3. If other users are selfless enough, they may consider editing somebody's else answer instead of giving a missing translation as an independent answer. But whose answer to choose? And if they are not selfless at all, we might end up with a lot of one-line answers, which are all more or less correct, but neither is full.

Answer (score 1):

I think all answers as well as the question should be merged to one community-wiki QA it this case.